# Write a Python function to ask the user to input a sentence

Tags: python

> Write a python function to ask the user to input a sentence. If the
>   sentence begins with a vowel, Return the sentence as it is to be
>   printed. If the sentence does not begin with a vowel, Change the first
>   letter to a capital letter and return the sentence to be printed.

This is what I came up with:

```
sentence = input("Enter a Sentence:")
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] 
if: (sentence.find [0]=vowels)    
     print (sentence) 
else: 
     (sentence[0].upper())
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions (most important point there: Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.)

Comment: @vencaslac I'm a beginner so this what i came up with

Comment: @vencaslacsentence = input("Enter a Sentence:")
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
if: (sentence.find [0]=vowels)
    print (sentence)
else:
    (sentence[0].upper())

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but your syntax is incorrect. see below

```
sentence = input('Enter a Sentence:')
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

if sentence[0] in vowels:
    print(sentence)
else:
    print(sentence.capitalize())
```